# Explain this call to optimize.fmin

Tags: python, scipy

```
def costFunction(theta, X, y, l):
...
```

`theta = optimize.fmin(lambda t: costFunction(t, X, y, 1), initial_theta, maxiter=1000)`

What's the `lambda t` doing here. What is it used for?

Comment: Please do not aggregate multiple independent questions into a bigger one. The question-answer format here at stackoverflow cannot handle such questions well. For each of your questions, provide a [mcve] for us and include the full error traceback you get.

Comment: Using the scipy docs relevant to your version are always a good idea. If you are just passing the optional parameters in the function call, the form of maxiter=1000 would be the appropriate way.

Comment: I figured 1) and 2), so just the 3) is missing. Will edit the question for just that one